# Django templateview not recognizing my template_name

Tags: python, django, frontend, django-settings

Currently I have in settings set my main directory to the templates folder so that I have a project level templates. Within that folder I have a home.html file.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

This is my views.py file:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name: "home.html"
```

Whenever I runserver I receive this error: ImproperlyConfigured at /
TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'

I'm following a book to the T (Django for Beginners) and I'm unsure why this error could be happening. Has the syntax for template_name changed? I've checked all the documentations and my name seems to be okay. I've also tried to input the pathname to the file instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the view incorrectly. Replace the `:` with `=` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are making an *annotation*: you should use an equals sign `=` instead of a colon `:`:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

Normally templates are also "namespaced" by putting these into a directory with the name of the app, so:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app_name/home.html'
```

and thus put the template in the directory of the `app_name/templates/app_name/home.html`. This prevents that you later would collide with a template with the same name in a different app.

Comment: Tested on Django **4.1.x**. `template_name` value should start with _admin_: `template_name = 'admin/app_name/home.html'`

Comment: @TruthTeller: likely that is due to the `TEMPLATES` config (in `settings.py`). If you set `APP_DIRS` to `True`, then you can add the template in the `app_name/templates/app_name/` directory: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/overriding-templates/